# Reading from txt file causes empty string with length 1

Tags: dart

I am reading from a txt file which has two lines, the first one containing numbers followed by a space. The second line is just empty.

```
1 2 3
```

Using the code below to read the file results in an error (`FormatException`). The fourth element of `tmp` is an empty string according to the debugger (see below), but has the length 1, according to the print statement, and is not caught by `removeWhere()`.

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() async {
  String filename = "text.txt";

  String content = await File("$filename").readAsString();
  List<String> lines = content.split("\n");
  List<String> tmp = lines[0].split(" ");

  tmp.removeWhere((element) => element.isEmpty);

  print(tmp[3].length);

  print(tmp.map((e) {
    return int.parse(e);
  }).toList());
}
```

Removing the empty line of the text file surprisingly solves the problem.
I do not understand the reason for the problem. Is there any solution?

[image: empty string]

Comment: Any reason why you are not using `readAsLines` if you already want to split the lines into a List<String> after reading the file? https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-io/File/readAsLines.html

Comment: Also, what platform are you using? Not all operating systems are using `\n` as newline. E.g. Windows are using `\r\n`. So if you are just removing `\n` you can still have `\r` which are used on Mac. You can read more about here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representation

Comment: All of this is handled by `readAsLines` which is another argument for using that method. :)

Comment: I am using windows and the problem was caused by CR LF line endings. `readAsLines`  solved this problem, thank you @julemand101!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably, the file is stored with CR LF line endings (Windows format). CR LF is `'\r\n'`. The lines are split by `'\n'`, so `lines[0]` is `'1 2 3 \r'`.

Store the text file with LF line endings (Unix format), replace all `'\r\n'` in `content` with `'\n'` before splitting, or use [LineSplitter](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-convert/LineSplitter-class.html), which accepts all line endings (CR, LF, and CR LF), or the readAsLines method directly. LineSplitter and readAsLines also strip the last line if it is empty.